# Firebase working in cmd but not in git bash

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, visual-studio-code, firebase-tools

I am building a react project on Visual Studio Code and want to use firebase but when I am giving the command `firebase login`, it says `C:\Users\ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found` but when I am running the same command using cmd it works fine.

Somebody pls help

Answer (score -2):

Try with:

```
firebase login --interactive
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.